# Pushing the limits to make a piece of code solving the K-Goodness String problem shorter

Tags: tips, python

I am trying to push my limits of making a python code as short as possible.

> I left the readability part way behind.

I was attempting the [**K-Goodness String** problem](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000436140/000000000068cca3) from Round A of Google Kick Start 2021.

The following was my initial solution:

```
def func(N, K, S):
    if not S: return 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(N//2):
        if S[i] != S[N-i-1]:
            y += 1
    return abs(K - y)

for i in range(int(input())):
    N, K = tuple(map(int, input().split(' ')))
    S = input()
    y = func(N, K, S)
    print(f'Case #{i+1}: {y}')
```

Then I shortened it down to the following:

```
def func(N, K, S):
    if not S: return 0
    for i in range(N//2): K -= S[i] != S[N-i-1]
    return abs(K)
[print(f'Case #{_}: {func(*tuple(map(int, input().split())), input())}') for _ in range(1, int(input())+1)]
```

I seriously want to push the limits. Can anyone help me shorten the *for loop* part:

```
for i in range(N//2): K -= 1 if S[i] != S[N-i-1] else 0
```

so that I can make a lambda function out of `func`, like:

`func = lambda N, K, S: 0 if not S else ...` #something

P.S. I can do it the following way, but that is inefficient and involves redundant steps that increase time and space complexity:

```
func = lambda K, S: abs(K - list(map(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], list(zip(S, S[::-1])))).count(True)//2) if S else 0
[print(f'Case #{_}: {func(tuple(map(int, input().split()))[1], list(input()))}') for _ in range(1, int(input())+1)]
```

Please suggest a good way to do the same.

> P.S. I know its not a good practice to compress a piece of code beyond readable, but I just wanted to do this for fun.

Sample Input

```
2
5 1
ABCAA
4 2
ABAA
```

Sample Output

```
Case #1: 0
Case #2: 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some example input? That way we could test this ourselves. And a description of what the function `func` is supposed to do would be helpful, as not every is familiar with that specific problem.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena That is untrue. [tag:tips] questions are on-topic here. [This meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/lets-decide-what-kind-of-non-challenge-questions-we-want-once-and-for-all) details these types of questions.

Comment: Could you add a summary of the challenge you're solving into your question? I put a link in, but questions should be self-contained. (also, let me know if the link I put in isn't right)

Comment: First of all, you can remove almost all of the spaces in your code: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY-xDoIwEIb3PsUZB3oKIk6GxMmRhIWREILaahMsTWkHQ3gSFxZ9El_CtxEU4nKX3H93X777U93MpZJd97CGe9v368Q4cCuPNHYhciHBkIDgICsDSaiZsVrCmgCvNAgQEnQhz4zGvr_BMPJ2SSqyWV9jT3hBRmC8KA41jZCkSgtpKHf2Rc1g3uRtCM2XtjBWlYxeC0X7DVdIZQ3FVa1K0XfEaYKtgwM7_7MDd_g55csAs5_LqDSpfQA

Comment: @ovs added the samples.

Comment: @user Thanks a lot for adding the link (yes it is correct). Also, I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Do you have control over the input format? [emanresu A suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237271/pushing-the-limits-to-make-a-piece-of-code-solving-the-k-goodness-string-problem/237276?noredirect=1#comment538413_237276) taking `K` as an array so you can do `K=eval(input())`

Comment: Try: abs(sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(s, s[::-1]))/2-k)

Answer (score 10):

#### 151 bytes by [@user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

Here is the 151-byte solution presented in [@user's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237276/88546). I recommend reading through their post for an explanation of how it works.

```py
for t in range(int(input())):N,K=map(int,input().split());print(f'Case #{t+1}:',0if not(S:=input())else abs(K-sum(S[i]!=S[N-i-1]for i in range(N//2))))
```

From here, three tricks can be used to shorten it by a significant amount:

- The edge case of having an empty string \$ S \$ is simply unnecessary. According to the constraints in the linked problem, \$ N \$ is always at least 1.
- `S[N-i-1]` gets the `i`th element from the back, but the same can be achieved with `S[~i]`, as mentioned [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41741/88546).
- `input` is used a total of three times. We can assign it to a variable with `I=input`, and reuse `I`.

#### 130 bytes

Combining these reduces the solution by 21 bytes:

```py
I=input
for t in range(int(I())):N,K=map(int,I().split());S=I();print(f'Case #{t+1}:',abs(K-sum(S[i]!=S[~i]for i in range(N//2))))
```

To go even further, we'll need a slight change in approach. In particular, `sum(S[i]!=S[~i]for i in range(N//2))` can be improved with some clever use of `pop`: `sum(c!=S.pop()for c in S)`. These are logically equivalent; for each character in `S`, we compare it to the last element with `S.pop()`.

#### 118 bytes

In total, we save 12 bytes this way. Note that we first need to convert `S` to a list via `*S,=input()`, since strings do not have a `pop` method.

```py
I=input
for t in range(int(I())):K=int(I().split()[1]);*S,=I();print(f'Case #{t+1}:',abs(K-sum(c!=S.pop()for c in S)))
```

#### 112 bytes

Finally, there is a 6-byte improvement by using `open(0)` instead of `input()`, a shortcut that essentially stores the list of lines from STDIN.

```py
_,*a=open(t:=0)
while a:K,(*S,_),*a=a;t+=1;print(f'Case #{t}:',abs(int(K.split()[1])-sum(c!=S.pop()for c in S)))
```

There is a lot to unpack here (no pun intended), so I will note some of the potentially confusing parts of the code.

`_,*a=open(0)` reads all input, and stores it as a list of lines. We unpack it by storing the first line in `_`, and the rest in `a`. `_` contains the number of test cases, but it is not needed for the rest of the program.

`while a:K,(*S,_),*a=a` removes the first two elements from `a`, and stores them in `K` and `S`. If we take another look at the sample input, what this is really doing is storing `5 1` in `K`, and `ABCAA` in `S` (as in the 1st test case).

The weird-looking `(*S,_)` is due to the fact that `open(0)` includes the `\n` at the end of each line, meaning that `S` actually equals `'ABCAA\n'` instead of `'ABCAA'`. The "nested unpacking" solves this by isolating the `\n` in `_`.

The `while` loop terminates when `a` is empty, or equivalently when there is no more input left.

Comment: In the final (112 bytes) approach, The program is taking continuous inputs and I can not  do anything (except causing KeyboardInterrupt by ctrl+C) to stop it. Also, due to some reason, I can't see the results of the print statements in the terminal. I am sorry, if I am asking something very obvious and silly, This is my first attempt in golfing.

Comment: @IshaanKapoor The issue is likely because of the `open(0)`. The program won't continue until all input is read. After pasting the input, try hitting Ctrl+Z then Enter to simulate an EOF.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a 176-byter after some trivial changes (based off of [pxeger's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237271/pushing-the-limits-to-make-a-piece-of-code-solving-the-k-goodness-string-problem?noredirect=1#comment538397_237271)):

```
def f(N,K,S):
 if not S:return 0
 for i in range(N//2):K-=S[i]!=S[N-i-1]
 return abs(K)
for _ in range(int(input())):print(f'Case #{_+1}:',f(*map(int,input().split()),input()))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY6xCsIwGIT3PMUvDk00tbYoSMAhdix06SilVGw0oGlI00HEJ3HporODL-Pb2NKiw3_8x90Hd3_qiz2WqmketRXu6vPaFwIEjmlEE8IQSAGqtJAwU9jaKJgjEKUBCVKBydWhwLHnBYRF7jrZynTUauxK108RDES-q3BEUEdlf0oq256uLSaEMG06L5wwrwoYX7Opf2MOFXhyznVXpUN1VumT7BD6Y_vdw_zmHaAl-IhvQs7RAoL247zPvg)

- You don't need to name your function `func`
- You can use a normal loop instead of a comprehension
- You can make a range starting at `0` and just add 1 to the case number when printing
- You don't need `tuple` (or even the shorter `list`) because `*` takes care of it
- You can make the result of `f` a separate argument to `print` to get rid of the braces

You're only calling the function once, so we can put that directly into the loop. To get around not being able to `return` from a function, we can try to turn the whole function into a single if expression. If `S` is empty, then it's just 0, but if it's not, we need to turn the for loop to decrement `K` into a single expression. The amount you're decrementing is `sum(S[i]!=S[N-i-1]for i in range(N//2))`, so the else part of the if expression is just `abs(K-<that sum>)`.

Once you do that, use semicolons instead of newlines, and use the walrus for assigning `S`, you get 151 bytes. (I renamed `_` `c` for readability)

```
for c in range(int(input())):N,K=map(int,input().split());print(f'Case #{c+1}:',0if not(S:=input())else abs(K-sum(S[i]!=S[N-i-1]for i in range(N//2))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3p6flFykkK2TmKRQl5qWnamTmlQBxQWmJhqamppWfjrdtbmIBSFQHKqpXXJCTCZK1LigCKU5Td04sTlVQrk7WNqy1UtcxyExTyMsv0Qi2soWZk5oDVJCYVKzhrVtcmqsRHJ0Zq2gbHO2nm6lrGAuyPxNhv5--vhHQZk2I86CuXLDFiMtUwZDL0cnZ0ZHLRMEIyHJ0hMgBAA)

Someone who knows Python and understands your algorithm can probably do much more, but these are some simple changes you can make. Edit: Yup, [dingledooper golfed it to 112 bytes!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237279)

Comment: You can [save a bit](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3F6ekpimkafjpeOsEa1pxKaTlFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnavjp6xtpWnnr2gZHZ8YqAkk_3Uxdw1guhaLUktKiPIVghcS8FIXEpGINb00ukN54hN7MvBIgLigt0dDU1LQqKALx09SdE4tTFZSr47UNa63UddI0tHITC0BKdaBK9YoLcjJBWnTgeiFOhbp4wRYjLlMFQy5HJ2dHRy4TBSMgy9ERIgcA) by making the return conditional.

Comment: @emanresuA Smart golf! Do you want to make your own answer?

Comment: Nah :P. Btw you can save a bit more if you take `K` as an array - `K=eval(input())` or something.

Comment: @emanresuA Wait, I don't think that'll work because you can't index into an empty `S` :(

Comment: Oops :P (filler)